# Whats the difference between Azure Data Catalog and Azure Purview

Tags: azure-data-catalog, azure-purview

I remember Azure Data Catalog V2 will be released soon which has the Data lineage features but I could see the same kind of service was introduced recently as Purview. Could you please shed some light on differences and when to choose these services?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can think Purview as the next generation of Azure Data Catalog, and with a new name. There will be no ADC v2, Purview is what Microsoft earlier talked with name ADC v2. Microsoft aims to profile it a bit differently and this way the new name is logical for many reasons:

- Featurewise Purview is much richer.
- There is no upgrade path from ADC to Purview.
- Pricing model for these products is different.
- ADC will be available for old customers yet for long time.
- Many have been disappointed with the features and lack of development progress for ADC. I assume Microsoft hopes that the new name does not carry this old weight.

The roadmap for ADC has been unknow, or dead, for long time. I personally have used it years ago and cannot recommend. I recommend using Purview for all new data cataloging and governance use-cases. It integrates with modern Azure data services and Microsoft is actively developing it forward.

Comment: Thanks, I had the exact same question